# How to use Jquery to access a div element 2 layers down

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the life of me I can't figure out how to access the first div with text "I want this one" starting with the id of div1

My attempt:

```js
$("#div1").first().first().html();
```

Here is an example

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="another">I want this one</div>
        <div class="another">Not this one</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, first you have to properly select div1. Then, you should use the proper jQuery methods. If you look to the documentation, clearly .first isn't what you want.

Comment: Fixed the selector.. clearly I wouldn't be asking if I knew :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1.

```
 $("#div1 .another:first").html();
```

2.

```
$("#div1 .another").first().html();
```

3.

```
$("#div1 .another").eq(0).html();
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jarifo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Note that `:first` is a jQuery extension, and as such, would be more performant if used separately. `$("#div1 .another").filter(":first")` or `$("#div1 .another").first();` http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: According to http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/ it's fastest to do `$("#div1").find(".another")` (followed by the rest).

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want the first element within the first element, you can do it in one selector using pure javascript selectors for performance like so:

```js
var row = $('#div1 > div:first-child > div:first-child');
alert(row.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="another">I want this one</div>
        <div class="another">Not this one</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="another">Another one</div>
        <div class="another">Yet another one</div>
    </div>
</div>
```